# proper way to convert byte[] to array with dots

Tags: java, string, byte, decode

I'm capturing data from a pcap packet; in my code I have a byte[] data and I want to decode to String using new String() constructor.

My code is the following:

```
byte[] data = payload.getByteArray(0, payload.size()); //jnetpcap, return a byte[] data
String datastr = new String(data);

Log.i("DNS PAYLOAD", datastr);
```

But the result throws:

> DNS PAYLOAD: ������������������apisecmiuicom������

Instead:

> DNS PAYLOAD: api.sec.miui.com

I need to replace all the unknowns "�" characters and get the link like above. Any sugestion?

PD: Using Array.toString(data), throws this:

> [-32, -51, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 97, 112, 105, 3, 115, 101, 99, 4, 109, 105, 117, 105, 3, 99, 111, 109, 0, 0, 28, 0, 1]

PD2: A payload String data (payload.toString()) looks like:

```
Data:  ******* Payload offset=42 (0x2A) length=107
Data:
002a: ab 7f 81 80  00 01 00 00  00 01 00 00  02 65 31 08    .............e1.
003a: 77 68 61 74  73 61 70 70  03 6e 65 74  00 00 1c 00    whatsapp.net....
004a: 01 c0 0f 00  06 00 01 00  00 00 e2 00  3e 03 6e 73    ............>.ns 
005a: 31 03 70 31  33 06 64 79  6e 65 63 74  c0 18 0a 68    1.p13.dynect...h
006a: 6f 73 74 6d  61 73 74 65  72 08 77 68  61 74 73 61    ostmaster.whatsa
007a: 70 70 03 63  6f 6d 00 78  3a 61 3e 00  00 0e 10 00    pp.com.x:a>..... 
008a: 00 02 58 00  09 3a 80 00  00 07 08                    ..X..:.....
```

And it's extracted from transport protocol UDP, port 53.

Comment: This is a question about string encoding - http://kunststube.net/encoding/. Your `new String(data)` interprets the bytes as the default encoding on your JVM platform (most likely UTF-8) which is clearly not working here. This needs a LOT more context, since it can be very arbitrary depending on which part of a raw packet you are trying to read and what protocols govern the encoding of the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could do a String.replace, but more correct:

```
int n = 0;
for (byte b : data) {
    if (32 <= b && b < 127) { // Within ASCII
        data[n++] = b;
    }
}
String datastr = new String(data, 0, n, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Comment: Yes, replace all the special unicode blocks "U+FFFD" (�) but erase the dots "." too.

And I can't use two parameters in "new String(data, 0, n, Standarscharactersets.US_ASCII);"  because I'm programming in android.